# Trying to find the board ID for Mac Pro 1,1 (no OS currently installed, can't access terminal)

Tags: macos, mail.app, osx-server, mac-pro, logicboard

I'm trying to install Mavericks on an old MacPro1,1 ([This one)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-3.0-specs.html), and I need the correct board ID to properly configure the USB install.  I currently do not have any OS installed on the HDD, so I cann't access terminal in order to find the board ID.

Does anybody know the board ID for this model?

Comment: I am not sure Mavericks will work with that hardware.

Comment: Mavericks will work on the MacPro 1,1 and MacPro 2,1.  Google "Tiamo boot.efi hack" or "64 on 32", I prefer 64on32 because they make a nice terminal script that will help create a thumbdrive installer.  Source: I just bought a 1,1 for $100 and installed Mavericks via thumbdrive.

Answer (score 6):

For the Mac Pro 1,1 and 2,1 you will need to add
"Mac-F4208DC8","Mac-F4208DA9".
If you are not using a Mac Pro then you will need to get your board ID by entering this
command in terminal: ioreg -lp IOService | grep board-id

Comment: Thanks for the 2 most requested board ID's (64on32 and Tiamo hackable) and a bigger thank you for the terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

To install Mavericks, you need one of these Macs:

```
iMac (Mid-2007 or later)
MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008), (13-inch, Early 2009 or later)
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or later),
MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later)
Mac mini (Early 2009 or later)
Mac Pro (Early 2008 or later)
Xserve (Early 2009)
```

Your Mac also needs:

```
OS X Mountain Lion, Lion, or Snow Leopard v10.6.8 already installed
2 GB or more of memory
8 GB or more of available space
```

Yours is 2006 model!

Since you can not see the logic board ID, you have to open the computer and find the label.

Answer (score 0):

According to MacTracker, the highest OS that computer can handle is OS 10.6.8.  So your best bet is a 10.6 install DVD.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the board ID for any mac:  I didnt write it, I poached it from somewhere....(just paste in the terminal as one line.

```
var_ID=$(ioreg -p IODeviceTree -r -n / -d 1 | grep board-id);var_ID=${var_ID##*<\"};var_ID=${var_ID%%\">};echo $var_ID
```

chris